# How to remove Stripe totally in Flutter?

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have bought a Flutter source code but when running in Android Studio or xCode the system noticed many errors about Stripe.

So please help me how to remove Stripe totally in my Flutter project because I don't need it.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Open pubspec.yaml. You will see stripe and some version in dependencies. Delete it. Now it will throw errors on all places stripe has been used. Delete them or fix codes as required.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the pubspec.yaml file and under dependencies you will see a package for stripe. Use the terminal and navigate to your project folder. then run this:

```
Flutter pub remove your_package
```

Then delete the error code in your project.